# Creating multiple Polygone

Tags: javascript, arrays, leaflet, polygon

what is the way for creating multiple poligones, but with different Names, Id's.
At the moment I'm creating the poligones in this way:

```
let Box1=L.polygon([
[429.99743, 505.374436],  // top left           P1
[428.393906, 505.374436],   // bottom left      
[428.393906, 506.9255941],  // bottom right     P2
[429.99743, 506.9255941]    //  top right
],{
//Set style for polygon object
fillColor: 'orange',
weight: 1,
opacity: 1,
color: '#641E8C',
dashArray: '1',
fillOpacity: 0.3
}).addTo(map)
```

As I need many of them, is there any way to create them like an Array in order to iterate over it?

BTW, it's a leaflet JavaScript app

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the polygons objects to an array and loop through them.

```
const polygons = [];

// Create polygons and add them to the array
const polygon1 = L.polygon([
  [429.99743, 505.374436],
  [428.393906, 505.374436],
  [428.393906, 506.9255941],
  [429.99743, 506.9255941]
], {
  fillColor: 'orange',
  weight: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  color: '#641E8C',
  dashArray: '1',
  fillOpacity: 0.3
});
polygons.push(polygon1);

// Add more polygons as needed
const polygon2 = L.polygon(/* 2nd polygon data here */);
polygons.push(polygon2);

// Iterate over the polygons array and add them to the map
polygons.forEach(polygon => {
  polygon.addTo(map); //or replace with any logic you need
});
```

This snippet has you manually add polygons, but depending on your needs you could add another method of adding polygons such as looping through existing data, from server responses, etc.

Comment: But i can not create these polygons with a Name that is created throughout a itteration? So i have to create each polygon 'manualy'